# Extracting local html file tables single column data to .csv file using python

Tags: python, html, excel, csv

I have a task to extract a table's column data from .docx  to a .xls or .csv file using python
whereas the Table looks like this below

#### Table 4-1. Bite_main.c

```
CHECK             Function      Line    Colum       Detail
=======================================================
##overflow.2        xxxxxxx     xxx     xxx         xxx
##overflow.5        xxxxxxx     xxx     xxx         xxx
##overflow.8        xxxxxxx     xxx     xxx         xxx
##overflow.12       xxxxxxx     xxx     xxx         xxx
```

#### Table 4-2. Bite_Engine.c

```
CHECK           Function    Line    Colum   Detail
overflow.4      xxxxxxx     xxx     xxx     xxx
overflow.9      xxxxxxx     xxx     xxx     xxx
overflow.8      xxxxxxx     xxx     xxx     xxx
overflow.10     xxxxxxx     xxx     xxx     xxx
```

Initially first I used "mammoth" library to convert the .docx file to .html file( because I checked in many websites that everyone are converting the .docx file to html for to make easier to deal with the data.)

Now I need to extract the "CHECK" column only for the each Table name(i.e like Table 4-1. Bite_main.c) from the converted html file in to the .xls or .csv sheet.
whereas it should look like this in xls sheet

```
1. Bite_main.c      overflow.2,overflow.5,overflow.8,overflow.12
2. Bite_Engine.c    overflow.4,overflow.9,overflow.8,overflow.10
```

### ---

---

I have used below code for to convert to html

```
with open("\input.docx", "rb") as docx_file, open("\out_file.html", "w") as myfile:
    result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file,      include_default_style_map=False)
    html = result.value
    myfile.write("%s" % html.encode("utf-8", "ignore")) # here one issue is I am getting all the file data in a single line of HTML file

After conversion, i tried to extract the table buti am not getting idea properly    

raw_html = open("\out_file.html", 'r').read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "html.parser")
        tables = soup.findAll("table")
        table_list = []
        for table in tables:
            table_dict = {}
            rows = table.findAll("tr")
           count = 0
            for row in rows:
                value_list = []
                entries = row.findAll("td")
```

I am not getting how to extract the data when I encounter "Table 4-1. Bite_main.c", and then extracting the "CHECK" column alone in the new xls sheet.
same thing i need to repeat for all the "Table 4.x. xxx.x".

I am very much new to the Python. 
Requesting to please provide the logic to implement this above concept or there any better way to deal with this.
Thanks in advance for those who answer for this.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and add the Output of `print(tables)`